# ForEach loop miss the comparation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, typescript, angular-material

I need to compare the element of to arrays of objects, and if the objects of the array #1 exist on the array #2 return nothing, but if the objects doesn´t exists push the object in to the array #2. Im using angular with typescript.

```
//Here i´m just open a confirmation windows
  public addSelectedContacts(ev: any): void
  {
    let confirm = this.$mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Are you sure want to add the selected contacts?')
        .htmlContent('<b>' + this.selectedContacts.length + ' selected</b>' + ' will be add to this Appplication.')
        .ariaLabel('add contacts')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('OK')
        .cancel('CANCEL');

    this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then( ()=>
    {
//Here is whent i´m try to compare the arrays after confirm the action
      this.selectedContacts.forEach( (contact:any)=>{
        if(this.application.clients.indexOf(contact) != -1){
          console.log('Exists!!!!');
        }else{
          console.log('Not Exists!!!!');
          this.applications.clients.push(contact)
        }
      });
      this.selectedContacts = [];
    });
  }

//They arrays will something like this
this.application.clients = [
        {
            "id": "5725a680b3249760ea21de52",
            "name": "Abbott",
            "lastName": "Keitch",
            "avatar": "assets/images/avatars/Abbott.jpg",
            "nickname": "Royalguard",
            "company": "Saois",
            "jobTitle": "Digital Archivist",
            "email": "abbott@withinpixels.com",
            "phone": "+1-202-555-0175",
            "sex":"Male",
            "country":"Germany",
            "website_url":"http://google.com",
            "publisher":"Michael Smith",
            "channel":"online",
            "linkedin_url":"http://linkedin.com",
            "xing_url":"http://xing.com",
            "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi quos perspiciatis voluptate debitis voluptas."
        },
        {
            "id": "5725a680606588342058356d",
            "name": "Arnold",
            "lastName": "Matlock",
            "avatar": "assets/images/avatars/Arnold.jpg",
            "nickname": "Wanderer",
            "company": "Laotcone",
            "jobTitle": "Graphic Artist",
            "email": "arnold@withinpixels.com",
            "phone": "+1-202-555-0141",
            "sex":"Male",
            "country":"Germany",
            "website_url":"http://google.com",
            "publisher":"Michael Smith",
            "channel":"online",
            "linkedin_url":"http://linkedin.com",
            "xing_url":"http://xing.com",
            "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi quos perspiciatis voluptate debitis voluptas."
        },
        {
            "id": "5725a6808a178bfd034d6ecf",
            "name": "Mai",
            "lastName": "Nox",
            "avatar": "assets/images/avatars/Mai.jpg",
            "nickname": "Violetmage",
            "company": "quadzone",
            "jobTitle": "Software Engineer",
            "email": "mai@withinpixels.com",
            "phone": "+1-202-555-0199",
            "sex":"Male",
            "country":"Germany",
            "website_url":"http://google.com",
            "publisher":"Michael Smith",
            "channel":"online",
            "linkedin_url":"http://linkedin.com",
            "xing_url":"http://xing.com",
            "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi quos perspiciatis voluptate debitis voluptas."
        }]
this.selectedContacts = [
        {
            "id": "5725a6808a178bfd034d6ecf",
            "name": "Mai",
            "lastName": "Nox",
            "avatar": "assets/images/avatars/Mai.jpg",
            "nickname": "Violetmage",
            "company": "quadzone",
            "jobTitle": "Software Engineer",
            "email": "mai@withinpixels.com",
            "phone": "+1-202-555-0199",
            "sex":"Male",
            "country":"Germany",
            "website_url":"http://google.com",
            "publisher":"Michael Smith",
            "channel":"online",
            "linkedin_url":"http://linkedin.com",
            "xing_url":"http://xing.com",
            "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi quos perspiciatis voluptate debitis voluptas."
        },
        {
            "id": "5725a68009e20d0a9e9acf2a",
            "name": "Barrera",
            "lastName": "Bradbury",
            "avatar": "assets/images/avatars/Barrera.jpg",
            "nickname": "Jackal",
            "company": "Unizim",
            "jobTitle": "Graphic Designer",
            "email": "barrera@withinpixels.com",
            "phone": "+1-202-555-0196",
            "sex":"Female",
            "country":"Germany",
            "website_url":"http://google.com",
            "publisher":"Michael Smith",
            "channel":"online",
            "linkedin_url":"http://linkedin.com",
            "xing_url":"http://xing.com",
            "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi quos perspiciatis voluptate debitis voluptas."
        },
        {
            "id": "5725a6809fdd915739187ed5",
            "name": "Blair",
            "lastName": "Strangeway",
            "avatar": "assets/images/avatars/Blair.jpg",
            "nickname": "Knight",
            "company": "Conedubdax",
            "jobTitle": "Visual Designer",
            "email": "blair@withinpixels.com",
            "phone": "+1-202-555-0118",
            "sex":"Female",
            "country":"Germany",
            "website_url":"http://google.com",
            "publisher":"Michael Smith",
            "channel":"online",
            "linkedin_url":"http://linkedin.com",
            "xing_url":"http://xing.com",
            "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi quos perspiciatis voluptate debitis voluptas."
        }]
```

But always give the the same result as "Not exists!!!" or always "Exists!!!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the answer thanks to the guys how answer before this, thanks for your answer even if you deleted it, but here is the code that was posted before.

```
this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then( ()=>
    {
      this.selectedContacts.forEach( (contact:any)=>{
        let exist = false;
        this.application.clients.forEach( (client:any) => {
          if (client === contact) {
            exist = true;
          }
        });
        if(exist){
          return;
        }else{
          this.application.clients.push(contact)
        }
      });
      this.selectedContacts = [];
    });
```

The only diferent if change the

```
      if (client === contact) {
        exist = true;
      }
```

for

```
      if (client.id === contact.id) {
        exist = true;
      }
```

Thanks you guys for the your ideas and help :D

Comment: You are welcome :) Don't forget to mark your answer as an answer as well :) I sadly enough didn't have the time to see it again and I don't know why the other user deleted it :(